# How to calculate week number as starting day Friday or Saturday?

Tags: c++, c

I want to calculate a week-number with "Saturday" or "Friday" as the starting day of a year. Year, month and day are given. There is an algorithm called ["DoomsDay algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) which calculates the week-number with Monday as starting day.

But I didn't find any algorithm for starting days "Saturday" or "Friday".

Comment: I'd imagine some modulo-7 arithmetic would work.

Comment: You've tagged this question C++, I'm pretty sure there are `Date` classes out there that can give you the DoW of any given date, either as a number or a string, after that, it's just modulo of the int representation of DoW + 1 for sunday, 2 for saturday, 3 for friday etc.. would do just fine

Comment: You can easily recalculate from Monday to Saturday or Friday

Comment: Just, in JS, because that's shorter to write, and you can test it in your console right here: `d = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` is an array of numeric DoW's (0 == monday, 5 == saturday), recalculating them is done _in a single line_: `for(i=0;i<d.length;++i) console.log(d[i] + ' -> ' + (2+(d[i]))%7);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually that algorithm starts with 0 as Sunday (C & C++ start counting from zero).

The algorithm adds an "anchor day" for the century.  This is just a fudge factor to get the days of the week to line up properly. If you subtract 1 or 2 from the total after this step (and before doing the division and modulus), the answer will be rotated forward, and now 0=Saturday (subtracting 1) or Friday (subtracting 2), etc.